# JQ: Filtering a massive json with nested arrays efficiently

Tags: json, jq

I have a MASSIVE json file with lots of extraneous fields that I need to trim down to only include certain fields. I've made some headway on processing the file with `jq` but I've run into some difficulty when it comes to pulling information out of the nested arrays in the json file, and none of the solutions I've found have seemed to work for me.

My json data looks like this:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "url": "https://someresult.com",
      "id": 5192740,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "web",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2022-04-29T15:19:37Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-29T15:19:38Z",
      "type": null,
      "subject": "My subject line",
      "raw_subject": "My subject line ",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et nulla ut sapien ultrices tempus.",
      "priority": "normal",
      "status": "new",
      "recipient": "somebody@email.com",
      "requester_id": 1234567891,
      "submitter_id": 1234567891,
      "assignee_id": null,
      "organization_id": null,
      "group_id": 123456789,
      "collaborator_ids": [],
      "follower_ids": [],
      "email_cc_ids": [],
      "forum_topic_id": null,
      "problem_id": null,
      "has_incidents": false,
      "is_public": true,
      "due_at": null,
      "tags": [
        "_tag_1",
        "_tag_2",
        "_tag_3"
      ],
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "id": 1500010396161,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "id": 360009431333,
          "value": "Keep this data"
        },
        {
          "id": 360054304553,
          "value": false
        },
        {
          "id": 1900000317745,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "id": 360002223154,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "id": 360009431353,
          "value": "Keep this too"
        },
        {
          "id": 1500001920482,
          "value": "Keep this data, as well!"
        }
      ],
      "followup_ids": [],
      "ticket_form_id": 12345678912,
      "brand_id": 112358,
      "allow_channelback": false,
      "allow_attachments": true,
      "result_type": "ticket"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://anotherresult.com",
      "id": 5192741,
      "external_id": null,
      "via": {
        "channel": "web",
        "source": {
          "from": {},
          "to": {},
          "rel": null
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2022-04-18T15:19:37Z",
      "updated_at": "2022-04-18T15:19:38Z",
      "type": null,
      "subject": "My other subject line",
      "raw_subject": "My other subject line ",
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et nulla ut sapien ultrices tempus.",
      "priority": "normal",
      "status": "new",
      "recipient": "somebody@email.com",
      "requester_id": 1234567892,
      "submitter_id": 1234567892,
      "assignee_id": null,
      "organization_id": null,
      "group_id": 123456780,
      "collaborator_ids": [],
      "follower_ids": [],
      "email_cc_ids": [],
      "forum_topic_id": null,
      "problem_id": null,
      "has_incidents": false,
      "is_public": true,
      "due_at": null,
      "tags": [
        "_tag_1",
        "_tag_2",
        "_tag_3"
      ],
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "id": 1500010396161,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "id": 360009431333,
          "value": "Keep this data"
        },
        {
          "id": 360054304553,
          "value": false
        },
        {
          "id": 1900000317745,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "id": 360002223154,
          "value": null
        },
        {
          "id": 360009431353,
          "value": "Keep this too"
        },
        {
          "id": 1500001920482,
          "value": "Keep this data, as well!"
        }
      ],
      "followup_ids": [],
      "ticket_form_id": 12345678913,
      "brand_id": 112359,
      "allow_channelback": false,
      "allow_attachments": true,
      "result_type": "ticket"
    }
  ],
  "facets": null,
  "meta": {
    "has_more": true,
    "after_cursor": "eyJmaWVsZCI6ImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiLCJkZXNjIjp0cnVlLCJ0aWVCcmVha0ZpZWxkIjoiaWQiLCJ0aWVCcmVha0Rlc2MiOmZhbHNlLCJzb3J0VmFsdWVzIjpbMTY0NjQxNTc3MjAwMCwxNTA5NDY0NjMzNTYyXSwiZXhwb3J0ZWRUaHVzRmFyIjoxMDAwLCJzZXNzaW9uU3RhcnQiOjE2NTE1MTA1MDE3MDksImNyZWF0ZWRBdCI6MTY1MTUxMDUwMTgxNywic2FsdGVkUmVxdWVzdEhhc2giOjEwMTMwNTk0MjMsInNhbHRlZEN1cnNvckhhc2giOi0xMTE3Mzc0MjIxfQ==",
    "before_cursor": null
  },
  "links": {
    "prev": null,
    "next": "https://myendpoint.site.com/api/v2/search/export.json?filter%5Btype%5D=ticket&page%5Bafter%5D=eyJmaWVsZCI6ImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiLCJkZXNjIjp0cnVlLCJ0aWVCcmVha0ZpZWxkIjoiaWQiLCJ0aWVCcmVha0Rlc2MiOmZhbHNlLCJzb3J0VmFsdWVzIjpbMTY0NjQxNTc3MjAwMCwxNTA5NDY0NjMzNTYyXSwiZXhwb3J0ZWRUaHVzRmFyIjoxMDAwLCJzZXNzaW9uU3RhcnQiOjE2NTE1MTA1MDE3MDksImNyZWF0ZWRBdCI6MTY1MTUxMDUwMTgxNywic2FsdGVkUmVxdWVzdEhhc2giOjEwMTMwNTk0MjMsInNhbHRlZEN1cnNvckhhc2giOi0xMTE3Mzc0MjIxfQ%3D%3D&page%5Bsize%5D=1000&query=group%3A360000609273+created%3E6Months"
  }
}
```

And I want to trim it down to this:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://someresult.com",
            "created_at": "2022-04-29T15:19:37Z",
            "subject": "My subject line",
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et nulla ut sapien ultrices tempus.",
            "recipient": "somebody@email.com",
            "tags": [
                "_tag_1",
                "_tag_2",
                "_tag_3"
            ],
            "os": "Keep this data",
            "is_signed_in": false,
            "phone_model": "Keep this too",
            "channel": "Keep this data, as well!"
        }
    ]
}
```

So far, I've been able to brute force it by deleting fields by typing them all out

```
jq 'del(.results[] | .url, .id, .external_id, .via, .updated_at, .type, .raw_subject, .priority, .status, .requester_id, .submitter_id, .assignee_id, .organization_id, .group_id, .collaborator_ids, .follower_ids, .email_cc_ids, .problem_id, .has_incidents, .is_public, .due_at, .forum_topic_id, .satisfaction_rating, .sharing_agreement_ids, .fields, .followup_ids, .ticket_form_id, .allow_channelback, .allow_attachments, .result_type)'
```

but that feels absurd (still, it works).
But when I try to delete or filter for the fields I want from the `custom_fields` array, I get stuck (`Cannot index array with string "custom fields"`).

My question is twofold:

1. **Is there a cleaner way I could be selecting which fields to *keep* rather than specifying which to delete?**
2. **How do I grab the fields I need from the nested array, and flattening them to the same level as the rest of the fields, while also renaming them?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mapping to keep track of the custom fields wanted :

```
!/usr/bin/env bash

jq '{"os"          : 360009431333,
     "is_signed_in": 360054304553,
     "phone_model" : 360009431353,
     "channel"     : 1500001920482} as $mapping |
.results |= map(
   { url,created_at,subject,description,recipient,tags,
   } +
   (.custom_fields as $custom_fields |
    $mapping |
    with_entries(
      .value |= (. as $id | $custom_fields[]?|select(.id==$id).value)
    )
   )
)' input.json
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in jqply, but when I try to run it on my full file, I get a `Cannot iterate over null (null)` error. I feel like I need a `try` in there somewhere to make it more robust in case one of my arrays is missing, but don't know where to stick the `try`.

(Side note Philippe - used a lot of your solutions to other questions! Thanks for looking here)

Comment: Can you paste a new sample into your question ? I made assumption that  `.custom_fields`  exists in all array elements.

Comment: I updated my sample - am I correct in suspecting the tag after the results is what mussed it up?

Comment: @MrSalta Updated, please retry.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! I see why that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following illustrates one approach to answering the twofold question:

```
.results |= map(
  (.custom_fields | map(.value | select(. != null))) as $values
  | {url, created_at, subject, description, recipient, tags, 
     os: $values[0],
     is_signed_in: $values[1],
     phone_model: $values[2],
     channel: $values[3] } )
```

This however results in .results having length 2.

Comment: Thanks peak. I ultimately went with @Philippe 's answer.